# Deadly protests ousted vs. deadly protests WHICH ousted

Tags: grammar

Source: http://news.yahoo.com/putin-warns-ukraine-gas-supplies-urges-talks-155039695.html

> Ukraine has been in crisis since months of deadly protests **ousted** an unpopular pro-Kremlin president in February and set the nation of 46 million on a westward course that prompted Putin to obtain the authority to use force against the ex-Soviet state.

I don't understand the reasons why a relative pronoun such as *which* or *that* was not used. My brain naturally wants to add one, otherwise it's difficult to tie the two parts of the sentence together. Don't you think that adding one would make the sentence sound much more clearer?

> Ukraine has been in crisis since months of deadly protests **which ousted** an unpopular pro-Kremlin president in February and set the nation of 46 million on a westward course that prompted Putin to obtain the authority to use force against the ex-Soviet state.

Comment: I think this is General Reference (Too Basic). You'd probably do better asking any future questions on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), where answers are more likely to be tailored to the needs of non-native speakers. The "target" of the word ***since*** is the point in past time represented by *entire* text following. Structurally, no different to the last three words in *"I've been happy since **I met you**"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Since* as a temporal preposition does not take a timespan as its object but a timepoint or event, expressed as either a noun phrase or a clause.

- <sup>ok</sup>John has been here since[<sub>date-noun</sub>May].
- <sup>ok</sup>John has been here since [<sub>event-clause</sub>Bill left].
- <sup>∗</sup>John has been here since [<sub>timespan-noun</sub>weeks].

As the sentence stands, the object of *since* is the events expressed as a clause: *months of protests ousted the president and set the nation on a westward course*. If you insert a relative, the object of *since* becomes *months*, a timespan noun, which is unacceptable.

---

∗ marks an utterance as unacceptable.

Comment: In my comment to the question, I originally included *Inserting the word "which" simply makes the sentence ungrammatical*, but removed it within the 5-minute "edit grace period". Basically because the example is so long-winded I found the grammar a bit taxing. But of course you're right (and so was I! :) - ***since*** must be used relative to *a "point" in past time*. And *months of protest* on its own doesn't fit that category, whereas *[the time when] those protests ousted the president* does. So *"**which**" cannot validly be inserted*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Exactly. And I think you're right that this is an ELL question; the equivalents to *since* in other languages (e.g. German and French) may take timespans.

Comment: If it *had* been asked on the right site, [your ELL answer there](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/15911/126) would in principle have contained everything necessary to explain why "which" wouldn't work for this example. Structurally, we'd end up with an utterance equivalent to *"Mosquitoes are surviving on earth since millions of years"*, as asked about there. I must say I do like your "event-clause" here though - is that "standard terminology", or just a term you made up to suit the context?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I just made it up, but I have no doubt somebody else has used it before me.

Answer (score 1):

**Ousted** is used alone here because it is the verb of a clause.

Break your long sentence down.

Ukraine *has been* in crisis since months of deadly protests **ousted** an unpopular pro-Kremlin president (stop here). It set the nation of 46 million on a westward course that prompted Putin to obtain the authority to use force against the ex-Soviet state.

The author is saying that *the protests drove out the president*.

similar to

The University *has been* in crisis since protests **toppled** an unpopular administration.

It would change the structure of the sentence to add *which*:

The University *has been* in crisis since protests which **toppled** an unpopular administration.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Cut out the qualifiers and simplify the sentence, in that secondary clause, to understand it better. Keep just a subject, verb, & object; what do we have then?  PROTESTS OUSTED A PRESIDENT  (protests being the subject). Then flesh out that simple sentence: "MONTHS OF" simply qualifies PROTESTS, UNPOPULAR qualifies PRESIDENT, etc.  Now take it from the beginning: Ukraine has been in crisis since [something happened].  What happened? Months of protests ousted an unpopular president.

Comment: I think someone's downvote was a bit harsh, so I've balanced it out with my upvote. IMHO this question has no business being asked on ELU anyway, but your answer does point the way to how less competent (or non-native) speakers should approach the example sentence - *remove structurally irrelevant qualifiers and secondary clauses **first***.